# Can the users can apply Windows update without local administrator rights?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, group-policy, wsus

My users are running on windows XP 32bit. normally WSUS automatically download and notify them to select which update want to install in the past they were in local administrator rights,now I reduce them to user rights so now they can't see the yellow notification said updated are available.
Is there a way to give users permission to see the yellow notification and they can select updates by hand without local admin rights or power users?
Any advice would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Are you in an active directory environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Computer -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update
Allow non-administrators to receive update notifications
```

This group policy setting controls whether users need admin rights to install updates.  If you lack GPO control over the systems, then use the equivalent registry hack:

```
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windowsupdate
ElevateNonAdmins
DWORD, set it to 1
```

Note that this setting only works up through Vista; in 7 it has no effect and admin rights are required for update installation.